# Is the summary-based interprocedural analysis method context-sensitive

Tags: static-analysis, program-analysis

```cpp
int foo(int x, int y, int *z) { 
    *z = 2;
    return x + y;
}
```

for function `foo`, I will get a symbolic summary:
input symbol: x, y
return value: x + y
side effect: *z -> 2

and when I apply this summary in different callsite with its prev state, I'll get different post state.

Can I say that the method based on symbol summarization is context sensitive? I did not directly bring the context into the current analysis stack frame or attach it to variables for further analysis, but I introduced symbol values to generate a summary after calculation. Then, the symbol summary can be instantiated and calculated based on different call point states. From the results, different call points may obtain different results, which requires combined analysis.

I just try to search the conception on internet, but I cannot find.